# Access to custom TCP Rule in AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, tcp-port

I had created a custom TCP rule in aws EC2 server.  And the inbound and the outbound rules for the rule is anywhere mean anyone can access the port.

But the port is not enabled. I was getting a problem like port is closed whenever I tried to check it using "yougetsignal".

Whereas being able yo access the common port 22. The problem is facing is only with the custom TCP rule I created.

What might be the problem?

[image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check two thing:

1. Your Network ACL's (VPC) - see if your traffic rules are ok
2. If you got no problems in number 1, check the following link:

[Ephemeral Ports](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_ACLs.html#VPC_ACLs_Ephemeral_Ports)

If you are using a custom VPC, you may need to add a ACL rule (ephemeral ports):
[ephemeral port rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vH1e.png)

Comment: ya everything is fine .Still am not able to access the port.

Comment: Hi bruno,thanks a lot for your response.I had followed the steps you said above.Still am not able to access the custom role.I even uploaded the screen shots of my settings.Once take a look at it.

Comment: followed the steps u said but still am not able to open the rule.